# Styling DateElement in Monotouch.Dialog

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uidatepicker, monotouch.dialog

I'm using MonoTouch.Dialog on my "settings" section on my app. 
When I use the `DateElement` the background is all black, which doesn't really match the rest of the app. Is there a way I can style everything around the "date wheels"?

Answer (score 4):

You can override the `CreatePicker` method of `DateElement`, e.g. in your own `MyDateElement` to create your own customized `UIDatePicker`.

Another option, for iOS 5.0 (and more recent releases) is to set the `Appearance` (static property) of `UIDatePicker` to the style you like (to match your application). That will ensure every `UIDatePicker`, created from MonoTouch.Dialog or yourself, will have the same look. E.g.

```
 UIDatePicker.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
```